# Ruby on Rails Active Record Associations, how i can do confirmation friendship(like on facebook)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I study RoR and do application like facebook.
1 user send request to 2 user for friendship. Second user have confirm friendship that they will be a friends

### Please say to me have i can do more simple that i need.

I have and do:
tables:

```
1. users
:id
:email
 (has_many :friendships, foreign_key: 'requester_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :requesters, through: :friendships, source: :requester
  has_many :responders, through: :friendships, source: :responder)
2. friendships
:id
:requester_id
:responder_id
 (belongs_to :requester, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :responder, class_name: "User"
  has_one   :confirm_friendship)
3. confirm_friendships
:friendship_id
:confirm
 (belongs_to :friendship)

That users have friendship i do:
u1 = User.first
u2 = User.second
u1.friendships.create!(responder_id: other_user.id)
fr = Friendship.find_by(requester_id: u1.id, responder_id: u2.id)
conf = ConfirmFriendship.create(friendship_id: fr.id, confirm: true)
```

Sorry for my English. Thanks a lot for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a number of the Rails based open source 'Social Networks' on Github. Here's a link(https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/develop/app/models/user.rb) to the `User` model of Diaspora which provides a good example to study.

If you are looking for the simplest implementation possible I would say you could try the following where you can do away with the `confirm_friendships` model and place a `confirmed?` boolean column on the friendships table.

Set `friendships.confirmed?` to default to false, and only once the responder accepts do you set it to `true`.

This then allows you to filter `user.friendships` with a scope such as:

```
scope :confirmed, -> { where("friendships.confirmed? = ?", true) }
```

To separate out which friends are in the confirmed status and which are not.

Perhaps you could simplify the models with something along these lines?

```
User
has_many: friendships

Friendships
belongs_to :requester, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :responder, class_name: "User"
```

It may be too simplified, but I hope something in this answer will be useful to you.